# Locate parent folder of NotesDocument instance

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

Attempting to locate the parent folder/view of a given instance of the [NotesDocument class](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/c4a6af5a62ba9d0b8525642e007687d5?OpenDocument) within a C# application using the Domino interop.

The goal is to use the `AllDocuments` property on the `NotesDatabase` and then ignore any documents which have been discarded by the user. It appears the `AllDocuments` view returns documents which were deleted out of the `$Trash` and thus remain within the database as a point of reference; I want to ignore those documents. In addition `ParentView` and `ParentDocumentUNID` are both null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "deleted out of the `$Trash`" do you refer to soft-deleted documents that appear in the `$Trash` or hard-deleted documents that have left deletion stubs?

Assuming that through the interop you have access to the mentioned properties:
For soft-deleted documents, [FolderReferences](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_FOLDERREFERENCES_PROPERTY_1349_ABOUT.html) might help. However it requires the database to have the $FolderInfo and $FolderRefInfo hidden views.
Hard deleted documents (deletion stubs) should only appear in the `AllDocuments` NotesDocumentCollection if they were deleted after you obtained the collection. In this case [IsDeleted](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ISDELETED_PROPERTY_8893_ABOUT.html) NotesDocument property might help.

`ParentDocumentUNID` returns empty string for documents that are not responses, it has nothing to do with deletion though. `ParentView` returns the view the document was retrieved from, in this case `Nothing`, because the document was not retrieved from a view.

Comment: Confused on the IsDeleted flag as it always appears false. If I could simply iterate over the AllDocuments property and ignore anything that was deleted that would be great but with the IsDeleted flag always returning false that does not seem possible. The end goal is sending the emails from the $Inbox, $Sent, and custom folders that the user created to an email address. If there is a better (easier) way to get the user defined folders that would be great.

Comment: If FolderReferences wouldn't help, it could be an option to construct an array of the UniversalIDs of all documents in the $Trash folder and check each document's UniversalID (of the documents you get using `AllDocuments` property) against those. You can get the $Trash folder using `NotesDatabase.GetView("$Trash")`, then iterate the documents using `NotesView.GetFirstDocument` and `NotesView.GetNextDocument`.

Comment: @Hristo The problem is that $Trash contains nothing and is in fact empty. I need to avoid the deletion stubs you mentioned which reside within the AllDocuments property.

Comment: @Hristo It also seems that the NotesID is valid; not empty. IsValid always returns true as IsDeleted always returns false.

Comment: @Aaron As I haven't done this through the Domino interop in my response I assumed that it would behave the same way it would when written in LotusScript. This is probably not always true and then my answer may not be worth much. I would expect a deleted document to be either soft-deleted (and appear in the $Trash folder) or hard-deleted (and IsDeleted return True). Actually, how do you know that AllDocuments returns also documents that are deleted?

Comment: @Hristo I am making an assumption the extra docs are previously deleted documents. If I go into my Inbox and Sent folders the sum is less then what the AllDocuments is returning. If I then go look at the All Doucments view as visible within Lotus Notes; there are emails which are in neither my Sent nor Inbox...leading me to believe they were deleted and are stubs.

Comment: Those could be a number of other documents including your contacts, appointments in your calendar, and To Do's. You can use the "Form" field in the document to sort them out - emails would be "Memo" or "Reply".

Comment: @Hristo I have sorted them out...memo, reply, appointment, notice, task, empty, and random other ones...my numbers seem a bit off. I believe the empty are the soft deleted items. The plan now is to simply filter out the memo and reply and use those as the valid emails to send to the new Inbox. Hopefully this shall suffice...